# spring boot container auto reloading at random times with intelij

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I wanted faster spring boot server reload which restarts the server faster than a cold restart after making changes to a Java class. This feature works out of the box in Eclipse but for Intellij IDEA one has to follow [addition steps like this](https://dev.to/suin/spring-boot-developer-tools-how-to-enable-automatic-restart-in-intellij-idea-1c6i).

I followed the steps and finally got the automatic restart working. In addition I disabled the auto-save feature of IDE because that was triggering server restart always when I make changes. Now when I make changes to a Java class and hit save, it is working as expected. But one problem is that the server restarts at random time even when I am not making any change whatsoever in the code.

Any idea what's causing it?

Comment: Have you tried Live Reload with spring-boot-devtools? See **Spring Boot Developer Tools** section here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/04/spring-and-spring-boot-in-intellij-idea-2018-1/

Comment: @Andrey Yes I am already using spring-boot-devtools. Auto reload is not possible without it.